# How do I route range of destination IPs to wireless interface on a workstation?

Tags: fedora, routing, vpn

**tl;dr** 
I need to route workstation VPN traffic through my wireless interface, and all other traffic through wired interface.

**More detail**

- I work remotely, and live in a remote area. My primary ISP is via satellite, which has decent speed but high latency. The high latency causes problems over the VPN. i.e. SSH handshake fails because of timeout
- OS is Fedora 27
- My VPN works with FortiClient SSL VPN.
- I have a strong lte signal and can use the VPN seamlessly when tethered to my mobile phone.
- I don't want to route all traffic over the wireless because cell data is more expensive.

I have to manually switch my laptop to wifi when I want to use the VPN. Is there a way I can route traffic to 10.10.x.x destinations through the wireless interface (after establishing the VPN connection), and have default traffic use the wired connection?

Comment: which OS do you use, solution might depend but that certainly possible

Comment: dang! I tried to be complete and efficient...forgot that important bit - Fedora

Comment: OK we're not done yet, what's your vpn software ?  what's it configuration ? Do not put anything sensible like public ip or shared key of course

Comment: We use Fortinet routers; my client is Fortinet's Linux desktop client. We use SSl VPN. What other config info do you need? I only had to add the IP of the gateway and the VPN port to the client

Comment: I don't have a centos/fedora/redhat at hand to help you more, but I'm sure it's possible. I don't know how Fedora handle network connection with Gnome.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can I add an entry to the routing table with `route` ?

Answer (score 3):

On multiple OS's the manual for `route` should be of some service.

In addition to this the majority of unix/linux distributions have ip functionality to force routes through specific interfaces based on subnet masking as part of the network interface configuration ensuring these performance / security optimized configurations remain persistent hrough restarts

Example

`$ route add -net 10.10.x.x netmask 255.255.255.0 dev wlan0`

Comment: The manual, understandably, assumes some knowledge of some bits. And I am lacking in those areas :-)

Comment: Using your example would 10.10.x.0 route any number in that 0 octet to wlan0 (from your example)? And, the VPN doesn't really come into play because it manages the routes after the route table?

Comment: @jas you shouldn't use `route` command nowaday but `ip route` VPN often create virtual interface so you want first a route to the VPN server through the wifi interface and then when VPN is up you want a route to 10.10.X.X through your VPN . => https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the new school methods implemented in RPM based distros. Roger, a VPN does indeed add or more specifically tells the IP stack that a new route exists for traffic destined to that interface and subnet mask provided by the new IPSEC tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check your current routes with `ip route`.

2) Note how the routes through your VPN interface are set up. Depending on your VPN client (which I don't know), you may have a `default` route. You also may have the old `default` route, and two `/1` routes to the VPN which override the default route, because they are more specific (`OpenVPN` does it that way).

3) Add a `10.10.0.0/16` route with the same parameters as the route through the VPN. The command should look something like

```
ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.12.34 dev vpn0
```

but of course it depends on your configuration.

4) Remove the route through the VPN with `ip route del`, using the output from `ip route`.

5) If you don't have a default route through the wired connection anymore, add one with `ip add default via ...`. You'll need the correct parameters, which are usually distributed from your router with DHCP.

6) It may be helpful to have a look at the configuration with and without the VPN, using `ip route`. As long as you keep this configuration somewhere, you can always restore your routing to a proper state manually while experimenting.